# Last updated email id using trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi i am facing a problem while creating trigger in `MySQL`. what i want is to take updated first name & last name using `email(which is unique`). `Is there any way to get the last updated email in trigger as per the like of`last_insert_id`?`

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: i have a scenario where two different databases are there and if i am updating some information in database A's table x then it should take email(which is unique) from that row and using that email id it should update the information in table y of database B